# Downgrade ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle 5 to 3.1 or install them side by side?

Tags: iis, asp.net, windows-server-2019

Windows 2019 Server with IIS and ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle 5.0.1 installed. I need to run Asp.Net Core 3.1 site on the machine. Should I just install ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle 3.1 side by side with the existing one or downgrade the installation in a way?

Answer (score 0):

Just installing ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle 3.1 alongside with 5.0.1 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle make IIS to know how to run core sites.
To run site with specific core version you need appropriate core runtime version to be installed or choose "self contained" build so runtime will be a pert of a build